# Angular - Add div every 3rd row

Tags: angular

I am trying to add `<div class="clearfix"></div>` every 3rd row within `ngFor`

Here is how I am doing it

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let foodMenu of item['food_menus']; index as i;">
    <div class="col-sm-4 food-menu-col"></div>
    <div *ngIf="i % 3 == 0" class="clearfix"></div>
</ng-container>
```

This does add it every 3rd row, however it adds after the first row as well, the code generates the following html.

```
<div class="col-sm-4 food-menu-col"></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 food-menu-col"></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 food-menu-col"></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 food-menu-col"></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 food-menu-col"></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 food-menu-col"></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 food-menu-col"></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 food-menu-col"></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 food-menu-col"></div>
<div class="col-sm-4 food-menu-col"></div>
```

Notice  added as the second row. I want to skip it. I want the clearfix div to be added after every 3rd row. I tried with following **condition**

`<div *ngIf="i > 1 && i % 3 == 0" class="clearfix"></div>`

Using this, the first clearfix div is added on the 5th row, and then after every 3rd row.

How do I go about adding clearfix div every 3rd row in the loop?

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change div clearfix to

```
<div *ngIf="i % 3 == 2" class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: This works. I wonder why my condition did not work and this did.

Comment: index `i` starts from 0,1,2,3,4,5,... so the value of `i % 3` is respectively "0,1,2,0,1,2,..." so `i % 3==2` is true for i=2, 5, ... . In your condition `i % 3==0` the true was for i=0,3,6,... (so for starting row i=0 too)

Answer (score 2):

The index begins with 0, that's why it's not every third. Try this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let foodMenu of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]; index as i;">
    <div class="col-sm-4 food-menu-col">{{foodMenu}}</div>
    <div *ngIf="(i + 1 )% 3 == 0" class="clearfix">I am added only every third one</div>
</ng-container>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3axjwo-ejtjx9)

Comment: Actually, that's similar to my deleted answer. I just realized OP doesn't consistently declare after the 3rd element. "This does add it every 3rd row" then in the following paragraph "I want the clearfix div to be added after every 3rd row." :(

Comment: This adds clearfix div every 2nd row instead of every 3rd.

Comment: You mean it should be after every third?

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirements. You want to add the `div` at third row.

Just replace the `index as i;` with `let i = index + 1;`.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let foodMenu of item['food_menus']; let i = index + 1;">
   <div class="col-sm-4 food-menu-col"></div>
<div *ngIf="i % 3 == 0" class="clearfix"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take 'i' as a variable in for loop it will start value of 'i' from 1.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let element of item; let i;">
  <div class="col-sm-4 food-menu-col"></div>
  <div *ngIf="i % 3 == 0" class="clearfix"></div>
</ng-container>
```